# IE browser takes so much time to execute the code after Certificate Error Block page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11, selenium-iedriver

I am using IEDriverServer_Win32_3.4.0 and Selenium selenium-java-3.4.0. While executing the code in IE browser, it takes almost 4 minutes to execute the remaining code after the Certificate Error Block page. Sometimes the browser hangs and the rest of the code fails.

Code Block:

```
 Set<String> allWindowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
          for(String handle : allWindowHandles)
            {
              driver.switchTo().window(handle);
            }
          driver.get("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click();");`
```

After this IE is not responding for almost more than 3 min, post that the remaining code is executed.

Error Stack:

> Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
>   3.4.0.0
>   Listening on port 33044
>   Only local connections are allowed
>   Jun 09, 2017 12:59:19 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
>   SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

Please let me know if any more information is required. Thanks.

Comment: Can you consider to showcase your work please? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB The purpose code is to do the following,
1. Get the url in IE and Click on login button, i am  moving my control to the new windows as

Set<String> allWindowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
          for(String handle : allWindowHandles)
            {
              driver.switchTo().window(handle);
            }

2. It will be redirected to the Certificate Error Block page, that i am handling  with driver.get("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click();");

After this the IE browser is idle for about 4 minutes and then it executes the remaining code.

Comment: So that essentially means `JavascriptExecutor` is unable to click the `overridelink‌`. So why shouldn't we try to look for some other ways? May be accepting the `Certificate` while configuring the webdriver instance?
 Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB It is actually able to click the overridelink. My problem is as on when the Certificate Error Block page appears the IE browser is idle for some moment and then starts executing the remaining scripts. That time taking is my only concern. Even i have tried without the javaScriptExecutor, but still the same problem occurs.